# Getting iOS 5 AVPlayer to display the last frame of the video when playback completes instead of a black screen

Tags: ios, ipad, video, ios5, avplayer

I am making some modifications to an iPad app written by somebody else and one of the things I need to fix is that the video needs to continue to show the last frame when playback is complete rather than the screen just going black.

On the iPad simulator using iOS 4.3, this is exactly what it does already, but it just goes black on iOS 5 (on both the simulator and a device).

Any suggestions on the best way to achieve this so that it works for iOS 5?  The code is using `AVQueuePlayer`.

Comment: i have same problem. I am using iOS6 and playing remote video. I used your solution below but it is not working for me. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I eventually found the solution:

```
[player setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause];
```

I'd already tried this and discarded it as not working, but I think I made the mistake of not setting it via the setter.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you didn't set it via the setter?